# Sorting the results of a DirectorySearcher query by DateTime

Tags: c#, sorting, active-directory

I have the following code:

```
// Declare new DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher
DirectoryEntry domainRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE");
string rootOfDomain = domainRoot.Properties["rootDomainNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
DirectorySearcher dsSearch = new DirectorySearcher(rootOfDomain);

// Set the properties of the DirectorySearcher
dsSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=Computer)";
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenCreated");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("operatingSystem");
dsSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

// Execute the search
SearchResultCollection computersFound = dsSearch.FindAll();
```

I want to sort the results by the `whenCreated` property in descending order, so that the newest computer objects are at the top.

I cannot simply do:

```
SortOption sortedResults = new SortOption("whenCreated", SortDirection.Descending);
dsSearch.Sort = sortedResults;
```

because the server returns an error (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/183a8f2c-0cf7-4081-9110-4cf41b91dcbf/)

What is the best way to sort this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it server side as mentioned in MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.sort(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
      new DirectorySearcher(entry)
      {
        Sort = new SortOption("cn", SortDirection.Ascending),
        PropertiesToLoad = {"cn"}
      };
```

The linked issue thread is solved:

> We have the same issue on AD Windows 2008 R2
>
> - applied kb977180-v2 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977180
> - and added key
>   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters
> - Add String value “DSA Heuristics”
> - Set the value to 000000000001
> - restart
> - after this issue solved

Answer (score 0):

Create comparer, that compares SearchResult instances by their whenCreated property

```
public class SearchResultComparer : Comparer<SearchResult>
{
    public override int Compare(SearchResult x, SearchResult y)
    {
        //Compare two SearchResult instances by their whenCreated property
    }
}
```

and then copy all items to list, that will use this comparer to sort items for you:

```
List<SearchResult> SearchResultList = new List<SearchResult>(computersFound);
SearchResultList.Sort(new SearchResultComparer());
```

Comment: In general, I would stick with a solution like the one above as server side sorts in AD are both resource intensive and failure prone with large result sets.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think this will work.  I will see what I can do.

Comment: I ended up creating a class that holds all of the AD attributes for me, then creating a SortedList<DateTime, CustomObject>'.  This allowed me to keep the elements of the list in order by date automatcally, and reversing the order was as easy as: 'IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, CustomObject>> revList = oldCompsList.Reverse();'