# LDAP Search for multiple names returns entries in a different order

Tags: c#, ldap-query

I work with an LDAP filter that is dynamically built to get the thumnailPhotos of a series of Active Directory users and place them in a Repeater

```
string UserIDs = "(|(SamAccountName=SummarS)(SamAccountName=RuatG)(SamAccountName=ArtisaD))" <- is build in a loop operation 
string OnlyEnabled = "!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)";
dsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)"+ UserIDs + "(" + OnlyEnabled + "))";
dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SamAccountName");
dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");

using (var results = dsSearcher.FindAll())
{
    var t = new DataTable("ActiveDir");
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserID", typeof(string)));
    t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("data", typeof(byte[])));
    int i = 0;
    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results)
    {
        Image SRC = RPT_Podium.Items[i].FindControl("ImgData") as Image;
        var bytes = searchResult.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[];
        MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        byte[] imageBytes = s.ToArray();
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        string imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
        SRC.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

To my surprise the returned results are NOT in the order of the AccountNames as appearing in the Search String. This forces me to reorder them somehow and I still can't think of the smartest way to achieve that

---

This is the solution I finally came up with:

```
string OU = "LDAP://DC=CORP,DC=ROOT,DC=INT";

string OnlyEnabled = "!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)";

DirectoryEntry startingPoint1 = new DirectoryEntry(OU);
DirectorySearcher dsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(startingPoint1);
dsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)"+ UserIDs + "(" + OnlyEnabled + "))";

dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SamAccountName");
dsSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");

using (var results = dsSearcher.FindAll())
{
    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results)
    {
        foreach(RepeaterItem ri in RPT_Podium.Items)
        {
            Label LBL = ri.FindControl("LBL_UserID") as Label;
            if(searchResult.Properties["SamAccountName"][0].ToString() == LBL.Text)
            {
                Image SRC = ri.FindControl("ImgData") as Image;
                var bytes = searchResult.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[];
                MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                byte[] imageBytes = s.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                string imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
                SRC.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you found a solution that works. You should consider to post it as an answer to your question, instead of editing your question. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Martin, I had thought about that, but stricktly speaking it's not a solution to the described problem - which can't be solved as it seems to be standard behavior of LDAP as jwilleke explained. Its a workaround I could have come up with in the first place, when I was too irritated that LDAP wasn't returning the results in the way I expected. I did not change my question, I just added the workaround. Its an ambiguous situation where I probably would have added the post of the workaround and marked it as the solution if I could have. But the 48 hours hadn't expired yet to do so.

Answer (score 2):

LDAP (the protocol) provides no guarantees as to the order of returned entries.

You Might be able to implement this server-side.
[Sorting the results of a DirectorySearcher query by DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158275/sorting-the-results-of-a-directorysearcher-query-by-datetime)

Or you would need to perform the sort on the client.

Comment: Thank you jwilleke for your comment. Knowing that the order can't be guaranteed helps already a lot in accepting the necessity of a workaround solution. Generally I know how to apply the sort criteria to the Directory Search Query, but not if the order is defined by the order of AccountNames as the appear in the filter string. I made these ID’s now available in the repeater and assign the picture while looping to the correct Repeater Item. I will post the solution.